# What is this snapping brick for / which set is it from?

Tags: part-identification, duplo

I've found this DUPLO brick:

[image: snapped out]

The red part can be pushed in and snaps out when the button on the top is pressed:

[image: almost snapped out]

Any idea which set this is from or what it could be used for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the Duplo Car Launcher and according to Bricklink this appears in at least 4 different sets: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=31080c01&in=S

Comment: Aha, interesting.  I could not launch any of our cars with it properly (they go off sideways), but maybe the race cars have the appropriate shape in the back.